# Image overflows sticky div dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sticky div in my page that has a height based on the screen size (so it can change between landscape and portrait) and an image inside it. I'm running into a problem where the image won't size itself correctly inside its parent `div`. I can't depend on the height of the container `div` since it's dependant on the screen size. I also can't depend on the height of the text above the image. Here's an example of the problem.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/vector67/pen/qRJXjd)

```
<div class="textHolder">
    <div class="sticky">
        <h3>Java script</h3>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.textHolder{
  margin:100px auto;
  width:700px;
  height:300px;
  background-color: #FFEEE7;
  padding:15px;
}
.sticky img{
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
.sticky h3 { 
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.sticky{
  position:-webkit-sticky;  
  position: sticky;  
  background:rgb(50,50,250);
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:5px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:46px;
  color:white;
  font-size:30px;
  top:10px;
}
```

Comment: can you change the html?

Comment: Yes I can in basically anyway necessary, but it needs to retain the functionality of the title being above the image in a container that is sticky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally understood what your were trying to achieve. You want the image size to adapt so it fits in the blue sticky block, while this block stays 100px high. Is that right ?

If so, you can do that with flexbox. Be careful though : it's is not supported by all browsers. But neither is `position: sticky`.

```
.sticky {
    /* Everything you already have here... */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNgZQx

Comment: It might just be me, but in chrome 55 your codepen doesn't do what it's supposed to do. The image still overflows the container.

Comment: You're right, It doesn't work on Chrome. I tested it with Firefox 51. That's the thing with new CSS properties... :-(

Comment: Just tested it in firefox, that's brilliant. I wish it worked in chrome the same way.

Comment: I'm trying to make it work in Chrome. But without success for the moment... The `flew-wrap: nowrap` default value does not seem to be handled well by Chrome. Same for `flex-shrink`.

Comment: Adding `min-height: 0` on the image force it to resize on Chrome. But then it doesn't keep ratio... I updated the Codepen.

Comment: If you just add object-fit: contain; then it works on chrome;

Comment: Nice ! I didn't know this one. I updated the Codepen, which is now working on Firefox and Chrome. Be careful, flexbox won't work on IE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135285/discussion-between-jeffrey-russell-and-eria).

Answer (score 2):

set the display to table for the .sticky element

```
.sticky{
  position:-webkit-sticky;  
  position: sticky;  
  background:rgb(50,50,250);
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  border-radius:5px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:46px;
  color:white;
  font-size:30px;
  top:10px;
  display:table;
}
```

demo:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxgOOq

Comment: Your answer is so close, but the image doesn't expand when the div increases in size.

Comment: @JeffreyRussell To expand/shrink the image along with its parents size, you should specify height or width of the image in percentages.

Comment: But i just noticed that you have stated that sticky `div` is of fixed height and width, probably that is why madalin suggested his answer.

Comment: Right, I've changed that in my question. This answer is perfect for the exact question I asked, but that wasn't exactly what I meant.